# I want to remove an attribute at loading time if window width is lower than something, it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code should work as explained:
Links in the article should see its target attribute removed (so it displays in the browser and not the iframe) but it doesn't. I make sure the window (with developper's tool) is the appropriate size, reload with ctrl+r, and it doesn't change.
I wish for this:

```
<a href="/glossaire/une-demarche-pionniere/" onclick="document.querySelector(&quot;iframe&quot;).removeAttribute(&quot;hidden&quot;)" target="iframe_glossary">démarche pionnière</a>
```

to loose its target attribute.

I tried:

```
<script>
if (screen.availWidth <= 604) {
   document.querySelector('p a').removeAttribute('target');
}
</script>
```

Edit:

Page structure:

```
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<script src="/livereload.js?mindelay=10&amp;v=2&amp;port=1313&amp;path=livereload" data-no-instant="" defer=""></script>
<script>$(window).Width<=604&&document.querySelector("p a").removeAttribute("target")</script></head>
<body class="page-template-default page">
<header id="header"><a href="http://localhost:1313/" id="logo"></a></header>
<div id=content>
<main id="page" class="page-content">
<article class="page-post">
<div class="post-ctt">
<p>C’est une
<a href="/glossaire/une-demarche-pionniere/" onclick="document.querySelector(&quot;iframe&quot;).removeAttribute(&quot;hidden&quot;)" target="iframe_glossary">démarche pionnière</a>
<iframe hidden="" name="iframe_glossary" allow-same-origin="" seamless=""></iframe>
<button onclick="document.querySelector(&quot;iframe&quot;).setAttribute(&quot;hidden&quot;,&quot;hidden&quot;)">☒</button>
</div>
</article>
</main>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: document.querySelector finds a single element.  I’m not sure if you were expecting *all* elements matching `p a` to have their targets removed, or if there is just a single such element.

Comment: We really need more information to help you.  For example, we don't know if you added this script tag before or after the anchor tag, and we don't know if the anchor tag is inside a p tag, like your query selector indicates.  Can you please post enough HTML where we can examine the page as you have it?

Comment: Since you say this should apply to "links" (plural), you need to use `document.querySelectorAll()` to find all the links. Then you'll have to loop over them with `.forEach()`.

Comment: The implication is that the iframe is shown/hidden based on screen width.  If you do that with `@media` queries (CSS) then the simplest option is to add *two* `<a>` tags and show/hide them with css as well.  (one with target, one without, if that wasn't obvious)

Comment: I had thought of that of course, but that's ugly code. If CSS can't change target, and I want to change it dynamically, so why not actually do that with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check the innerWidth not the screen's entire available width. also your script runs before the content is there, try waiting for DOMContentLoaded

```
<script>window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {window.innerWidth<=604&&document.querySelector("p a").removeAttribute("target")})</script>
```

To handle more than one element, do `document.querySelectorAll` and forEach over it

```
<script>window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {window.innerWidth<=604&&document.querySelectorAll("p a").forEach(a => {a.removeAttribute("target")})})</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't want an eventlistener, that's overkill. So just
<script>window.innerWidth<=604&&document.querySelectorAll("p a").forEach(a => {a.removeAttribute("target")})</script> should suffice ?

Comment: @MehdiSaada The event listener is only fired once, it's not overkill lol. The reason it's needed with your code is your JS is running before the HTML elements it's looking for. another way to fix that is put your script **after** the elements in the body.

Comment: Ok. Can defer and/or async have the same effect ?

Comment: @MehdiSaada async no, but defer yes. but for defer you need to use the script src attribute instead of inline script

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm.
I use:
<button onclick="document.querySelector('iframe').setAttribute('hidden', 'hidden');">☒</button>
<script>window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {window.innerWidth<=604&&document.querySelectorAll("p a").forEach(a => {a.removeAttribute("target")})})</script>

Answer (score 0):

`screen.availWidth` doesn not work when you manually resize browser size. It works when tried with difference device sizes (try responsive feature on dev tools)

To make this work, try `window.innerWidth`. It gives correct width when browser/window is resized.

Comment: I had misunderstood that document.querySelector applied to all elements matching the css selector. I published the simplified html code so you can see the layout.
The snippet is meant to serve browsers so is not for resizing windows, but if it can do that without additional load, I wouldn't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript executes before the HTML element you are selecting exists, so there is nothing to select at that time.
Change this line:

```
<script>$(window).Width<=604&&document.querySelector("p a").removeAttribute("target")</script>
```

To this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  if( $(window).width() <= 604 ){
    document.querySelector("p a").removeAttribute("target");
  }
});
</script>
```

Now your javascript will execute after all the HTML on the page has loaded, and it will work.  If you want it to execute when someone loads the page with a width greater than 603, but then resizes the screen to less, the use $(window).on('load resize', function(){... instead of document.ready.

Comment: I added
"<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  if( $(window).width() <= 604 ){
    document.querySelectorAll("p a").forEach(removeAttribute("target"));
  }
});
</script>" just before </body>, opened the page, resize (with developper's tool) and refresh within a very small window, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Just want to make sure:  you have jQuery installed?  This solution assumes you have jquery.  You could add this above the code if you don't have it:  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>